# Is theinverse of a dissipative operator dissipative?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ Hilbert and let $A \colon D(A) \subset X \to X$ be linear and dissipative, i.e.
$$\langle Ax,x \rangle \leq 0$$
Now suppose that it is invertible with inverse $ A^{-1} \in L(X)$ (linear, bounded, continuous). Does it follow that $A^{-1}$ is dissipative?

Comment: Would it follow from $\langle A^{-1}y, y\rangle=\langle A^{-1}Ax, Ax\rangle=\langle x,Ax\rangle \leq 0$?

Comment: yes that does the job!